# How can I display text on the window

Tags: tkinter

like the print function, i want my text to appear on the window in such a way that after the BMI calculation is done, it would be written as your BMI is _____ and their BMI would be displayed on the window. here's the code:

```
def submit():
h = bmi1.get()
w = bmi2.get()
bmi3: float = int(h)/float(w)**2
print(bmi3)
```

Comment: `l1 = Label(root,text=f'BMI is {bmi3}')` and then `l1.pack()` or `grid()` as what is there in your code

Comment: This should be covered in just about every tkinter tutorial. Why do you need our help? Have you read about the Label widget, or the Text widget, or any of the other widgets which accept text?

Answer (score 0):

Below is some abstract code that you may find helpful. You should create your label to BMI in outside the submit function, so if you want to calculate again later the function will just configure the already existing Label.

```py
bmi_label = Label(window_obj)
bmi_label.pack()

    def submit():
        global bmi_label  # Sometimes it is necessary to declare a used variable as global; you may not need this line.
        h = bmi1.get()
        w = bmi2.get()
        bmi3: float = int(h)/float(w)**2
        bmi_label.configure(text=str(bmi13))
```

It is best to include enough code to have a running example, so we aren't to assume how the rest of the program looks as there are many ways to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Hey Shayne I’m totally new to programming can u explain what is window_obj and what does bmi_label.config do?

Comment: window object... ```window_obj = Tk() ``` so whatever you named your window a lot of people use root for their first window. I didn't know what yours is called so I just used ```window_obj``` as a placeholder.

Comment: A label object called  bmi_label is created with ```bmi_label = Label(window_obj) ```, but the label is empty. To change the object afterwards you use the configure() or config() method. ```bmi_label.configure(text="my label text")``` would change the text of the label, but you can pass other configurable parameters as well.